# How does bitwise AND OR and XOR works on -negative signed integers?

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bitwise-and

I was just solving random problems on `bitwise operators` and trying various other combination for making personal notes. And somehow I just cannot figure out the solution.

Say I wanted to check bitwise AND between two integers or on a ~number and -negative number(~num1 & -num2) and various other combo's. Then I can see the answer but I haven't been able to establish how this happened?

**Console:**

> console.log(25 & 3); outputs 1 (I can solve this easily).
>
> console.log(-25 & -3); outputs-27.

**Similarly**

> console.log(~25 & ~3); outputs -28.
>
> console.log(25 & ~3); outputs -24.
>
> console.log(~25 & 3); outputs -2.
>
> console.log(~25 & -3); outputs --28.
>
> console.log(-25 & ~3); outputs --28.

I know the logic behind **"console.log(25 & -3)"**.

> 25 is 11001 
> -3 is 11101(3=00011 The minus sign is like 2s compliment+1) 
> AND-11001 = 25.

But I cannot make it work the same way when both the numbers are negative or with the other cases mentioned above. I have tried various combinations of numbers too, not just these two. But I cannot solve the problem. Can somebody explain the binary logic used in the problems I cannot solve.

(I've spend about 2 hrs here on SO to find the answer and another 1 hr+ on google, but I still haven't found the answer).

Thanks and Regards.

Comment: Did you check other questions with similar issues? If so, reference them and let us know why its not working for you.

Comment: I did tried to find the case that could be similar but i didn't found any case that would have asked the same question. Every single place and even on multiple websites, everybody has discussed the problem involving one positive and one negative integer, which is fairly simple to do. For this reason, rather than wasting time in searching, i thought to come here. Rest assured if i get the question similar to mine, i will surely mark you. 

BTW @PSKocik below did gave a very easy and beautiful example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**JavaScript specifies that bitwise operations on integers are performed as though they were stored in two's-complement notation**. Fortunately, most computer hardware nowadays uses this notation natively anyway.

For brevity's sake I'm going to show the following numbers as 8-bit binary. They're actually 32-bit in JavaScript, but for the numbers in the original question, this doesn't change the outcome. It does, however, let us drop a whole lot of leading bits.

```
console.log(-25 & -3); //outputs -27. How?
```

If we write the integers in binary, we get (11100111 & 11111101) respectively. AND those together and you get 11100101, which is -27.

In your later examples, you seem to be using the NOT operator (~) and negation (-) interchangeably. You can't do that in two's complement: **~ and - are not the same thing**. ~25 is 11100110, which is -26, not -25. Similarly, ~3 is 11111100, which is -4, not -3.

But when we put these together, we can work out the examples you gave.

```
console.log(~25 & ~3); //outputs-28. How?
```

11100110 & 11111100 = 11100100, which is -28 (not 28, as you wrote)

```
console.log(25 & ~3);//outputs-24. How?
```

00011001 & 11111100 = 00011000, which is 24

```
console.log(~25 & 3);//outputs-2. How?
```

11100110 & 00000011 = 00000001, which is 2

```
console.log(~25 & -3);//outputs--28. How?
```

11100110 & 11111101 = 11100100, which is -28

```
console.log(-25 & ~3);//outputs--28. How?
```

11100111 & 11111100 = 11100100, which is -28

The real key to understanding this is that **you don't really use bitwise operations on integers. You use them on bags of bits of a certain size, and these bags of bits happen to be conveniently representable as integers**. This is key to understanding what's going on here, because you've stumbled across a case where the difference matters.

There are specific circumstances in computer science where you can manipulate bags of bits in ways that, *by coincidence*, give the same results as if you'd done particular mathematical operations on numbers. But this only works in specific circumstances, and they require you to assume certain things about the numbers you're working on, and if your numbers *don't* fit those assumptions, things break down.

This is one of the reasons Donald Knuth said "premature optimization is the root of all evil". If you want to use bitwise operations in place of actual integer math, you have to be absolutely certain that your inputs will actually follow the assumptions required for that trick to work. Otherwise, the results will start looking strange when you start using inputs outside of those assumptions.

Comment: Correct, i forgot the last bit is used as a sign bit. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

`25 = 16+8+1 = 0b011001`, I've added another 0 digit as the sign digit. Practically you'll have at least 8 binary digits
but the two's complement math is the same.  To get -25 in 6-bits two's complement, you'd do `-25 = ~25 + 1=0b100111`
`3=2+1=0b000011; -3 = ~3+1 = 0b111101`

When you `&` the two, you get:

```
-25 = ~25 + 1=0b100111
&
-3 = ~3 + 1 = 0b111101
              0b100101
```

The leftmost bit (sign bit) is set so it's a negative number. To find what it's a negative of, you reverse the process and first subtract 1 and then do `~`.

```
~(0b100101-1) = 0b011011
```

thats `1+2+0*4+8+16 = 27` so `-25&-3=-27`.

For 25 & ~3, it's:

```
25 = 16+8+1 = 0b011001
&        ~3 = 0b111100
______________________
              0b011000 = 24
```

For ~25 & 3, it's:

```
~25 =         0b100110
&        ~3 = 0b000011
______________________
              0b000010 = 2
```

For ~25 & -3, it's:

```
~25 =         0b100110
&      ~3+1 = 0b111101
______________________
               0b100100 #negative

#find what it's a negative of:
~(0b100100-1) =~0b100011 = 0b011100 = 4+8+16 = 28
               0b100100 = -28
```

Comment: Your's was the easiest answer i wasn't even expecting. I understood it in a minute and tried solving another problem too and got the exact result too. Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 2):

The binary string representation of a 32 bit integer can be found with:

```
(i >>> 0).toString(2).padStart(32, '0')
```

The bitwise anding of two binary strings is straightforward

The integer value of a signed, 32 bit binary string is either

```
parseInt(bitwiseAndString, 2)
```

if the string starts with a '0', or

```
-~parseInt(bitwiseAndString, 2) - 1
```

if it starts with a '1'

Putting all that together:

```js
const tests = [
  ['-25', '-3'],
  ['~25', '-3'],
  ['25', '~3'],
  ['~25', '3'],
  ['~25', '~3'],
  ['-25', '~3']
]

const output = (s,t) => { console.log(`${`${s}:`.padEnd(20, ' ')}${t}`); }

const bitwiseAnd = (i, j) => {
  console.log(`Calculating ${i} & ${j}`);
  const bitStringI = (eval(i) >>> 0).toString(2).padStart(32, '0');
  const bitStringJ = (eval(j) >>> 0).toString(2).padStart(32, '0');
  output(`bit string for ${i}`, bitStringI);
  output(`bit string for ${j}`, bitStringJ);
  const bitArrayI = bitStringI.split('');
  const bitArrayJ = bitStringJ.split('');
  const bitwiseAndString = bitArrayI.map((s, idx) => s === '1' && bitArrayJ[idx] === '1' ? '1' : '0').join('');
  output('bitwise and string', bitwiseAndString);
  const intValue = bitwiseAndString[0] === '1' ? -~parseInt(bitwiseAndString, 2) - 1 : parseInt(bitwiseAndString, 2);
  if (intValue === (eval(i) & eval(j))) {
    console.log(`integer value: ${intValue} ✓`);
  } else {
    console.error(`calculation failed: ${intValue} !== ${i & j}`);
  }
}

tests.forEach(([i, j]) => { bitwiseAnd(i, j); })
```

Comment: Code copied for future references my friend. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

-27 has 6 binary digits in it so you should be using numbers with at least that many digits. With 8-bit numbers then we have:

- 00011001 = 25
- 00000011 = 3
- 00011011 = 27

and:

- 11100111 = -25
- 11111101 = -3
- 11100101 = -27

Now -25 & -3 = -27 because 11100111 & 11111101 = 11100101